# Как правильно расставить блоки один под другим

Tags: html, css

Нужно вот таким образом расставить блоки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это сделать правильно, без костылей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку ("на клавиатуре") появился тень на соответствующую кнопку дай знать.

**Ответ обновлен:**

```css
   
.container{
display: grid;
transition: 0.5s;
position: relative;
display: flex;
}
.left, .right{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #363636;
border-radius: 7px;
color: #5D5D5D;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
font-size: 25px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25) inset;
}
.up, .down{
width: 100px;
height: 48px;
margin: 0px 5px 4px 5px;
background-color: #363636;
border-radius: 5px;
color: #5D5D5D;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
font-size: 14px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25) inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">◀</div>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="up">▲</div>
        <div class="down">▼</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">▶</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант на [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50px);
  grid-template-areas: 
    'L U R'
    'L D R';
  grid-gap: 5px 10px;
}

.container .btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #222;
  color: #444;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25) inset;
}

.container .left {grid-area: L;}
.container .up {grid-area: U;}
.container .down {grid-area: D;}
.container .right {grid-area: R;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn left">◀</div>
  <div class="btn up">▲</div>
  <div class="btn down">▼</div>
  <div class="btn right">▶</div>
</div>
```